# Probability of choosing among married couples

Tags: probability

5 Married couples are at a party, 4 of which will be selected for a similar prize. The only condition is that the no two member of the same couple can be selected for the same prize.

My solution:

Since we have 5 couples ${M_1,W_1}..{M_5,W_5}$

Hence we can pick one couple the following:
${2 \choose 1}{2 \choose 1}{2 \choose 1}{2 \choose 1}{2 \choose 0}$ and 
Since there are ${5 \choose 4}=5$ to distribute those 1's. Hence, the answe should be $5*2^5$=160. But the answer is 8-. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A probability is in the interval $[0,1]$, so I don't understand how the answer could be 8. What is the exact question?

Comment: If I understand the problem, your procedure is right. But it gives $80$ ways. Typo?

Comment: Yea I think so. for some reason I did $2^5$ instead of $2^4$ very sorry. Another way to solve the problem is to imagine 4 slots. For the first slot there is 10 ways to select someone, the second slot has 8 ways of selecting someone, third has 6 and the 4th has 4 ways. And since we picked the members one-by-one in an order, we divide by 4!. Are there any other creative way any of you guys of breaking the sets up and finding the same solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume that the problem goes as follows. We have $4$ identical prizes, and want to find the number of ways to distribute them.

Your procedure is correct, there was just a numerical slip.  The $4$ couples one of whose members will get a prize can be chosen in $\binom{5}{4}$ ways. For each chosen couple, there are $2$ ways to decide which of the members will receive a prize, for a total of $\binom{5}{4}2^4=80$ ways.